# Do the new characters ever wonder about olders muses of Robert Langdon?

Tags: character-analysis, dan-brown, inferno, origin-langdon

I was reading *The Origin* by Dan Brown, and wondered if Ambra Vidal ever thought about whatever happened to Sienna Brooks - Langdon's muse from *Inferno*?
Or Sienna must have vetted Langdon knowing his past, did she ever wonder what happened to Sophie Neveu - Langdon's muse from *The Da Vinci Code*?

To be more specific, when a new character meets with Langdon, they might also remember his previous adventures but they never seem to mention... even in a casual conversation, and that makes me curious.
Considering all Langdon novels are a journey, the new characters do not much muse over the previous stories or victories.

Also, the other way around .. does Langdon keep in touch with any of his previous muses? Except for Sienna, I think he ended on a decently good note with everyone including Sophie Nauve, Vittoria Vetra, etc.

Comment: Having read all of Dan Brown's novels, I don't recall a single time previous women were mentioned. I think Brown is less interested in creating a coherent story cycle, instead using references to previous events as throwaway jokes.